# SyntaxError: missing : after property id angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to execute the following code, but it gives me this error:

[image]

```
$http.post('/api/updatePhoto/'+$scope.item.id)

$scope.onFileSelect = function($files) {

     for (var i = 0; i < $files.length; i++) {

         var file = $files[i];

         $scope.upload = $upload.upload({

         $http.post('/api/updatePhoto/'+$scope.item.id) 

          data: {myObj: $scope.myModelObj},
          file: file,
      })

    }).success(function(data){
   alert(data);

  })
 }
```

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: Please always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$upload` object you specified needs an object to work, you're declaring an invalid  object at:

```
 $upload.upload({
      $http.post('/api/updatePhoto/'+$scope.item.id) 
      data: {myObj: $scope.myModelObj},
      file: file,
  });
```

The $upload object needs a `url` property, like this:

```
$upload.upload({
    url: '/api/updatePhoto/' + $scope.item.id,
    data: {myObj: $scope.myModelObj},
    file: file,
});
```

This way you're passing an actual javascript object to the `upload` function.